# sys_write outputting extra characters

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

So I'm writing a menu-based program that can display a message (among other things that I haven't implemented yet). I have the following segment:

```
mov rax, 1
mov rdi, 1
mov rsi, msg
mov rdx, msg_len
syscall
```

For whatever reason, this outputs the string stored in `msg`, plus all the other strings I have stored in my `.data` section. I've run the program with gdb and printed the contents of both rsi and rdx right before the system call - they contain the string I want to output and the length of that string, as expected. But after the system call, `rax` contains 2048. If I understand it correctly, this means that 2048 characters were written to the console - way more than the 30 I had specified right before the system call. I guess the other strings I have were stored right after where `msg` is stored in memory, which is why they get output, but why is it ignoring rdx?

For what it's worth, the code works fine if `msg_len` is immutable, but I need it mutable because `msg` can change.

Comment: Wouldn't `mov rdx, msg_len` load the address of `msg_len` rather than the value that's stored there?

Comment: No, it loads the value stored there. I checked.

Comment: When you say "mutable", do you mean `msg_len: dq msg-$` to label some static storage?  If so, then yes, `mov rdx, msg_len` puts the address in the register, and `sys_write` goes until it hits unmapped memory (because that's sooner than the very large length).  IIRC, it does actually return the length written, not `-EFAULT`.  Otherwise you probably did `msg_len equ msg - $` in the wrong place, like after all your data. Anyway, this is obviously not a [mcve].

Comment: TL:DR: assemble-time EQU constants vs. data in memory are totally different ways to use symbols / labels, not "mutable" vs. "immutable".  I know you say you printed RDX, but are you sure you didn't dereference it when you printed?  The system call won't.

Comment: You are running this under Linux, right?

Comment: But if I use EQU for `msg_len` then when I try to change it later the code segfaults. Right now I have it with `db` and it doesn't segfault.

Comment: And yes, I'm using LInux

Comment: `mov [msg_len], al` of course segfaults if `msg_len` is a small integer constant, because that virtual address isn't mapped.  There is no storage for it in memory.  It's an assemble-time constant.  If it's in memory, you need `movzx edx, byte [msg_len]`.  Your question is *not* a [mcve] of what you're doing.  If you did `mov rdx, msg_len` when it was `msg_len: db 10`, you definitely did not have RDX = 10 or something, you'd have an address = some large number.

Answer (score 0):

You said it outputs all the strings when you tried to output just one of them, called `msg`.

You can make a loop using `CMP` and `JE` (or `JZ`, they are same) to count until `NULL`. You can then use this number as `LEN` to print strings.